# Concurrency Issue occuring After making the method as synchronized also

Tags: java, web-services, concurrency

I have a method in the Web Service Which is performing some database insertions. I want single access to that method that is why I have made a method as synchronized. But when multiple calls are made to this method at same instant synchronized option didn't work.
The structure of the method looks like this

```
public synchronized void display() {
   //DataBase updations and Transactions.    
}
```

Can anyone suggest any soln through which this issue can be avoided.

Comment: what do you mean by "But when multiple threads called this method at same instant synchronized option didn't work"? How did you check this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with the method but with the multiple instances of your code containing this method.

Answer (score 0):

How do you determine that the synchronization doesn't work? You are aware that synchronization works on *object* level, so if the method is in a servlet and the servlet container creates several instances of this servlet, you're out of luck - each servlet instance can run the "synchronized" method simultaneously.

Also, why do you want to serialize the DB operations in code - any DB is perfectly capable of doing just that, cf. transactional and the ACID principle.

Cheers,

Comment: yes...This synchronization will only work if he is using singleton instance of that class.

Comment: Actually there was a insertion operation happening inside this method. I wanted that to execute with single access. But right now what is happening that multiple calls with same data trying to insert inside db thats why i had to made this method synchronized. As synchronized was not working in my case both threads entered the method and try insertion at same time which has resulted in form of constraint violation error. And i cannot lock the table as it is referred somewhere else also there by not degrading the performance.

Comment: Well, wouldn't you get a constraint violation *even* if the two insertion were serialized? Hint: Yes you would. You need to rethink your architecture.

Comment: well checks are there if the entry is there in database or not.. problem is that when both the threads pass through check whether the entry is there in database or not insert is happening after that both threads passed that condition.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following -

1. Create a separate class which deals with your all database operations like - insert, delete, create table etc..
2. Make synchronized all methods.
3. This class should be initialized once in your code.
4. Create a database connection out side from this class and set that connection to this class (This setter method must be synchronized). Remember connection should be created once in your code like object of above class that deals with database.
5. Then use the same object of this class in multiple threads. That should be worked.

Comment: Hi Ashish Actually there was a insertion operation happening inside this method. I wanted that to execute with single access. But right now what is happening that multiple calls with same data trying to insert inside db(I have made checks which will check whether the data is aleready there or not) thats why i had to made this method synchronized. As synchronized was not working in my case both threads entered the method and try insertion at same time which has resulted in form of constraint violation error.

Comment: @Naman I have updated my answer please check and let me know.